# Datatable replace incorrect row with null

Tags: c#, datatable

The image below is the result of DataTable. I have used `RemoveEmptyEntries` to remove all the white spaces. As I am using text file, now my main issue is that if some data on certain rows is missing, then the missing rows will be replaced by rows data from next index of row.

[image: datatable result]

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Datatable 
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        /// DB connection

        string filepath = @"C:\Users\2563911\source\repos\test1.txt";
        using (System.IO.TextReader tr = File.OpenText(filepath))
        {
            string line;

            while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                if (!line.StartsWith("-"))
                {
                    if (line.Length < 82 || line.Contains("MY01"))
                    {

                        string[] items = line.Replace("MY01", "").Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                        try
                        {
                            if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
                            {
                                // Create the data columns for the data table based on the number of items
                                // on the first line of the file
                                for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
                                {
                                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column" + i, typeof(string)));

                                }
                             }

                            dt.Rows.Add(items);
                            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                            {
                                if (!dr[4].Equals("1"))
                                {

                                }

                            }                                
                        }

                        catch (System.ArgumentException c)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(c.Message);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            //show it in gridview
            dt.Columns.RemoveAt(1);
            this.DataGridView.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```

However, what should I do to modify this segment `if (!dr[4].Equals("1"))` in order to get the below result as shown below?

- CISCO 08-072        08-0729-01    1   EA
- CISCO 08-072        08-0729-01    1   EA
- CISCO 08-072        08-0729-01    1   EA
- CISCO 10-291        10-2919-01    1   EA
- CISCO 10-299-01$1   10-2919-01    1   EA
- CISCO 10-299-01$1   10-2919-01    Null   EA

Comment: Did you try `if (!dr[4].Equals("1")) dr[4] = (string)null;`

Comment: It works, but my "EA" was overridden and it was suppose to be appended into new index of the row

Comment: if EA is overridden, then I would suspect the way how items are populated - items does not look like it has synchronous rows.  So, try removing ` StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` from the Split function. If you could share sample test1.txt file content then we could assist further.

Comment: Found solution, just put  dr[5] = dr[4].ToString(); on top of your code as it assign the value to next index of the row if detected null values